# 144Hz monitor stuck at 60Hz

Tags: xrandr, nvidia-settings, xorg.conf

i have the last nvidia-352 driver and after a reboot my monitor return to `auto` 60Hz instead of 144Hz.

I tried `sudo nvidia-settings` and saving the configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it doesn't work.

I have tried the same thing in Kubuntu and my configuration is saved after a reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Ask  Ubuntu . Could you accept cbll's answer as it works for you,  please make a look on https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers and [about] pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to add the command in your configuration including all the parameters.

I had the same issue. Adding `xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144.00`, where you of course have to identify your parameters by just running `xrandr` and setting your DVI/HDMI output correctly.