# High refresh rate monitor stuck at 60hz

Tags: drivers, graphics, kubuntu, external-monitor

So i have a 3440 x 1440 - 144hz monitor that used to work fine in both Ubuntu and Kubuntu but after running some updates it is stuck on 60hz (almost feels like 50 or 40 tho). I was running Ubuntu Gnome for a while and after updating to the latest LTS version the problem occurred, i never solved it. About a week ago i switched to Kubuntu and the problem occurred today again.

Im running a DP to USB Type-C cable to my Thunderbolt4 port which works fine in windows on the same system (although on 120hz i think). So the laptop and cable is capable. The laptop is an ASUS VivoBook S14 with i5-1135G7 and no dedicated GPU (so Intel Iris Xe graphics). When i go in Display Configuration in Kubuntu i can only pick 60hz and nothing else on the monitor.

Any tips on this one? I wonder if some driver came along and "broke" it.

Edit: Right after posting this i got it working for a second. What i did was i set the "Replica of:" to the same monitor (like what?) and then i could pick 120, 144. I picked 120 which seemed to work and then i picked 144 but that set me back to 60 and with no option to change again. Now i can't replicate it either. This almost seems like a bug in the interface to me instead of a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am running **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** with a **Nvidia RTX 2070 Super**.

**I had the same problem:**
My main monitor uses 2560x1440 as resolution and supports refresh rates up to 165Hz. So I wanted to use this refresh rate.

In the GUI of settings I didn't even have the the option to change the refresh rate. So I researched a bit and tried to set the refresh rate with xrandr, (`xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 165`) but this didn't work either. There was no error message, but it did't change anything.

**Solution:**
It actually was really simple. I just had to install the latest driver and the nvidia-settings for my graphic card. In the GUI of nvidia-settings I could simply change the refresh rate to the preferred one.

A guide to install the driver and nvidia-settings:

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/09/04/nvidia-rtx-2070-super-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation/2/

(This is only for the RTX 2070 Super, but the steps are probably the same with any other nvidia card.)

Answer (score 0):

From: [144Hz monitor stuck at 60Hz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723297/144hz-monitor-stuck-at-60hz)

Sometimes, you need to add the command in your configuration including all the parameters.

I had the same issue. Adding xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144.00, where you of course have to identify your parameters by just running `xrandr` and setting your DVI/HDMI output correctly.

Comment: i ran `xrandr` and got this 
`DP-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
   3440x1440     59.97*+
   2560x1080    143.94    59.98    60.00    59.94    50.00  
`. 
So then i ran `xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 3440x1440 --rate 120`. Is that correct? nothing happened, Im a bit of a linux noob.

Comment: Ok, i have no clue what is happening. I ran `xrandr` today and now the high refresh rates showed up again, unlike yesterday. Then i went to the system settings and i could change it from there too. Its like the monitor reports 59.97 as the max (at 3440x1440) only sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is usually the issue with (Nvidia) dedicated cards when stuck at 60Hz (2K) - even when Windows supports more (e.g. 75Hz). If there is no way to change it with GUI (nor Terminal).

If an updated driver doesn't help when using HDMI, then changing to DP can solve the problem - connects to (dedicated) graphics card directly and/or the DP itself supports higher Hz (and fps).

Nvidia drivers are not fully open source even today.

Monitor, graphics card (dedicated), driver(s), ports and cable all need to support the Hz (and fps). (The CPU and GPU also dance together, as does the power needed, and RAM needs.)

The major problem is that 60Hz (and fps) is not sufficient for quality, nor for health (depends on distance also).