# Laptop Monitor stuck at 60hz (supports 100hz)

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, monitor

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Hey there! I have an Asus ROG G751JY Gaming Laptop. It has an Nvidia 980M Graphics Card. Its monitor supports 100hz refresh rate, (I tested it in Wind*ws).

But xrandr only outputs this:

```
z@YY:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
z@YY:~$
```

I have the [Version](https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/rog-gaming-notebooks/i-have-the-g751jy-but-refresh-rate-option-is-only-60-hertz-why/td-p/614961) of the Laptop that supports 75/100hz.
[image]

In the Nvidia Settings, I can only select "60hz" as well.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350411/high-refresh-rate-monitor-stuck-at-60hz) Question on Askubuntu, and followed its steps:

run `xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 100`, the screen goes blank for a second, and then comes back and its still only 60hz, in all settings (it also doesn't feel like 100hz).

I am using the nvidia-driver-525, (535 is the latest, and it broke minecraft 1.8 so I cannot use it), but even on 535 this problem still persists.

I also tried the following:
`cvt 1920 1080 100`
which outputted:

```
# 1920x1080 99.90 Hz (CVT) hsync: 114.58 kHz; pclk: 302.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync
```

then:
`xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync`

but when I try:

```
z@YY:~$ xrandr --verbose --addmode DP-2 "1920x1080_100.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

it fails.
It also fails when I only try to do 75hz.
It also fails when I try to do 60hz.

Does anybody have a solution for this problem? And if not, could anybody recommend any external monitors with higher refresh rates to use with the system?

Thanks in advance!